# How to handle low-level net/http errors?

Tags: go, httpserver

With my golang net/http server, I occasionally get errors like

`2017/08/04 15:06:25 http: Accept error: accept tcp 127.0.0.1:80: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s`

on stderr. There might be a bug with a missing `Close()` somewhere, but this is *not* what my question is about.

What I would like to know is whether there is an easy way to catch these or similar errors programmatically in go? <strike>I only know about this error because it's logged. `ListenAndServe()` does not return an error. Is there some other way to get notified of errors like these?</strike> Specifically: how do I access the errors of the underlying listener? `ListenAndServe()` does not return errors from the underlying listener (at least not all of them).

(edited)

Comment: What other "errors like these" are you referring to? Do you specifically want to intercept the `Accept` calls, and if you did, what would you even do with said error besides log it and retry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to get a stack trace for 'http: response.WriteHeader on hijacked connection' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547565/any-way-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-http-response-writeheader-on-hijacked-connect)

Comment: I'd even go a step further than JimB and say that this log entry did *exactly* whatvit was supposed to do: have you check wether you close all files and presumably check the maximum number of open file descriptors provided for the user running the process  by the OS. Root cause solved is what I call mission accomplished.

Comment: @JimB yes, intercepting `Accept()` is what I want. Upon catching one of these, I would terminate the program. In my case, that's better than retrying because the error is likely to persist. Termination is a good workaround until the actual bug causing these errors is fixed.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Correct, but until the root cause is eliminated, I need a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how `(*http.Server).Serve()` is implemented [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?m=text), it is clear that you can just define your own class that implements `net.Listener` and give it to the `Serve()` function, instead of using `ListenAndServe()`, which puts a default listener there. Make it `panic` on error and later `recover` from that panic in your code, or implement any other error handling logic.

Comment: The question isn't about errors returned from `Server()`, but errors that are only logged.

Comment: What happens in that case is that `http.ListenAndServe()` creates the default `http.Server` and runs `server.Serve()` providing a default `net.Listener`. Then, if an `accept error` happens (inside Listener), it just gets printed by the server. What I have proposed is that you define your own Listener, which just wraps around the default `net.Listener` and performs your custom logic on errors. I should probably edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: That helps with `error`s; this question isn't about `error`s.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Sorry for causing confusion due to my mentioning the logs.

Answer (score 2):

net/http logs all errors to [server.ErrorLog](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server). You can use that to intercept the log messages, but it is not obvious how much data you can pull from those logs programatically.